# javascript setInterval how it works in details

Tags: javascript, function, setinterval

I've wrote this code and it surprises me.

I do not understand why the function is called but executed only first 2 lines, then setInterval waits 1 second and execute return statement.

Please, somebody explain it to me :)

```js
let div = document.getElementById("div1");
const updateTime = () => {
  let seconds = 0;
  if (seconds === 0) div.textContent = `0 sekund`;
  return () => {
    seconds++;
    div.textContent = `${seconds} sekund`;
  }
}
setInterval(updateTime(), 1000);
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Your code seems to work...

Comment: Simple, the `setInterval` runs (every 1,000 ms) until you call `clearInterval`, but you have to reference ID, so there is no way to stop it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute updateTime() immediately, it performs the first two lines and then, also immediately, returns the function that is run first time 1 second later and then every second after that

Please read the comments I wrote in the code:

```js
let div = document.getElementById("div1");
const updateTime = () => {
  // next two lines executed by updateTime() immediately
  let seconds = 0; // these are remembered because you create a closure
  if (seconds === 0) div.textContent = `0 sekund`;

  // NOW the following function is returned and will be what is 
  // executed for the rest of the life of the setInterval
  // The first time this returned function is called is in one second from now
  return () => { // this creates a closure. It is a good way to handle vars
    seconds++; // this is known only to the function 
    div.textContent = `${seconds} sekund`;
  }
}
setInterval(
  updateTime(), // execute this IMMEDIATELY 
  1000 // execute whatever is returned from updateTime in intervals of 1 seconds 
 );
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: You could also re-write it, and explain that the scope of `seconds` is internal so that you do not need to store it's value in the global namespace. It's a self-executing/returning function.

Comment: But why return()... isnt excecuted immediately with entire updateTime function like in Java? :D

Comment: Because it is not an IIFE

Comment: The same reason `var x = function() { alert("y"); }` is not executed until we do `x()` but this is: `(function() { alert("y"); })()`

Comment: @YourDoom Alas no

Answer (score 1):

The `updateTime` function runs when you call it, which is when you type `updateTime()`.

All of it runs.

The part of it after the `return` keyword is syntax which *defines another function*. It doesn't run immediately, because you haven't done anything to call it.

That other function is returned.

You are passing that function to `setInterval` which calls it every second.

Comment: Yes, you are right... I should take a break after 16h+ marathon with JS... seems like i dont understand simply words anymore. Thanks.